# Weird situation with a table column's value fetching

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.3

I'm retrieving data from **Database** like everyone else, but I'm facing a weird issue.
I'm using the slug in my table to retrieve the element's data but but I display the slug it gives me `null`and using the famous `dd()`famous it shows up here is an example :

```
dd($element);
```

### Result

[image: gitbits dev]

```
dd($snippets->toArray());
```

### Result

[image: gitbits dev]

### Table

```
Schema::create('elements', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('slug')->unique();
    $table->text('body');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

### Eloquent

```
$snippets = Snippet::latest()->with('owner')->get();
```

### Snippet Model

```
protected $primaryKey = 'slug';

public function owner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

Is there any one who knows what is going on?

Comment: How does your snippet model look?

Comment: @Daniel I've added it

Comment: Looking at your Model it seems you intend `slug` to be your primary key. However you have not defined it as a primary key in your Schema with `$table->primary('slug')`. Before running this you should know that `$table->increments('id');` automatically sets the `id` as the primary key - and to change that you need to include `$table->dropPrimary('id');` before you set `slug` as the new primary key.

Comment: @Daniel will try that thank you

Comment: @Daniel SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table def
  inition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
  (SQL: alter table `snippets` drop primary key)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the `Primary Key Type`, by default is set to **int** and have not set incrementing to false which is causing it to 'cast' it by the keyType. The `keyType` is set to 'int' unless set otherwise. `(int)'es2015' == 0`

```
protected $keyType = 'string';
```

Thanks everyone for help